# Merging 2 files based on single column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to merge two files. I looked upon the previous questions and answers but none of them match my desired output.

I have two comma-separated files, of different lengths, `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`.

I need to merge these files based on their first field. If the first field from `file1.csv` is present in `file2.csv`, then the corresponding line from `file2.csv` should be appended to that of `file1.csv`. If the 1st field is not present, then the line from `file1.csv` should be printed and `no match` appended to it.

`file1.csv` (4 columns):

```
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C#
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#
```

`file2.csv` (7 columns):

```
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1, SignalP-4.1, SIGNAL, 1, 22, 0.808, YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_8_2, SignalP-4.1, SIGNAL 1, 20, 0.877, YES
```

Desired Output:

```
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1 [1169 - 963] (REVERSE SENSE),MQGHRRKLATPRQRAPRKERQRALLLRLQWRIGLQPCSRRNKSLDRKNIYWRYLVEYGSWKGRTHISDV,C#,Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1, SignalP-4.1, SIGNAL, 1, 22, 0.808, YES
Contig_Spider_Gland_98_7_3,>Contig_Spider_Gland_98_17965_1 [90 - 278],MADVEKTSCCTETKECCKDETCCENGQGACHTGKEECKDTCHKKACGCKAGEDCKCSDGKCGC,CC#CC#CC#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#C#,no match
```

Comment: Not too important, but is each entry in the csv files really separated by an empty line?

Comment: no, they are not separated by empty line. I added empty line to visualize two different lines

Comment: Ok, I removed the empty lines because that way it's easier for people to copy-paste-test; last question, are the files sorted? If not, could they be sorted before processing? It can be done either ways however for large files sorting would be *highly* recommended

Comment: yes the files are sorted. But they are of different length. and File 1 has much more rows then file 2

Comment: Ok, very last thing, is file1 a superset of file2? i.e. is each entry contained in "file2.csv" contained also in "file1.csv"?

Comment: Can you have more than one entry for each contig name? For example, can `Contig_Spider_Gland_98_1_1` be present multiple times in one of the two files?

Comment: Yes thats true. file1 is a superset of file2. and there are no multiple entries in any of the files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}
                   {
                      if(a[$1]){print $0,a[$1]}
                      else{print $0,"no match"}
                   }' file2.csv file1.csv
```

#### Explanation

- `awk -F, -vOFS=,` : run `awk`, setting the input (`-F`) and output (`-vOFS=,`) field separators to `,`.
- `(NR==FNR){a[$1]=$0; next}` : `NR` and `FNR` are special variables which mean the current line number and the current line number of the *current file* respectively. When passing more than one file name, the two will be equal only while the first file is being read. So, this means "while reading the first file, save each line in an array whose key is the first field and move to the next line".
- `if(a[$1]){print $0,a[$1]}` : we are now in the second file. If the current line's 1st field was also in the 1st file, print the current line and the line from the first file.
- `else{print $0,"no match"}` : if the 1st field wasn't in the first file, print the current line and "no match"

Note that I am passing `file2.csv` as the first file and `file1.csv` as the second. This is because one of the two files needs to be stored in memory so it is better to store the smallest of the two.

Comment: I apologise but somehow it is not merging both files and gives the answer as no match. I tried three times and made sure about file order too. any suggestions??

Comment: @Trupti it works fine on the example files you gave. Maybe your real data are different? Have you tried it on the examples from your question?

Comment: you are right. it works well on the data provided. my file has exactly same data but I check once again

Comment: Is there anyway that I can send my file? I am unable to edit more lines correctly

Comment: I checked it works well on the sample file wit 2 entries, but does not work correctly on my long file :(. I do not have any multiple entries

Comment: Found the reason probably .  in my file1.csv  it shows a space before , in ID field. Might it be the reason for no correct answer

Comment: I apologise for all the troubles. Everything works well. The problem was in my own file. It had space before , in the ID field and thus was unable to match

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @kos no, `if(a[$1])` checks whether `a[$1]` is defined.

Answer (score 1):

This should do (shortened(R) and fixed(TM) by terdon):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV==2 || die;

open(my $file1, $ARGV[0]) || die("Could not open \"$ARGV[0]\": $!");
open(my $file2, $ARGV[1]) || die("Could not open \"$ARGV[1]\": $!");

$"=","; #" (this comment exists only to prevent syntax hilighting from breaking)

while(my $l1 = <$file1>) {
    chomp($l1);
    my @f1 = split(",", $l1);
    if(my $l2 = <$file2>) {
        chomp($l2);
        my @f2 = split(",", $l2);
        if($f1[0] eq $f2[0]) {
            print("@f1,@f2\n");
        }
        else {
            push(@f1, "no_match");
            seek($file2, -length($l2), 1);
            print("@f1\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        push(@f1, "no_match");
        print("@f1\n");
    }
}

close($file1);
close($file2);

exit;
```

Since the files are sorted, "file1.csv" is superset of "file2.csv" and there are no duplicate lines in either files this:

- Compares the next lines in both files;
- If the first field of the line from "file1.csv" matches the first field of the line from "file2.csv", appends the line from "file2.csv" to the line from "file1.csv" (comma-separated) and prints the generated line; otherwise appends a "no_match" field to the line from "file1.csv", goes back one line in "file2.csv" and prints the modified line from "file1.csv";
- If "file2.csv" has no more lines, appends a "no_match" field to the line from "file1.csv" and prints the modified line from "file1.csv".

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use join:

```
join -t, file1.csv file2.csv -a 1 -o auto -e 'no match'
```

If the input files are not yet sorted you can do so in one go:

```
join -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) -a 1 -o auto -e 'no match'
```

Exlanation

- `-t,` sets the field seperator
- `-a 1` ensure that all unpairable lines are printed as well
- `-o auto` sets the output format
- `-e 'no match'` replaces missing input fields with 'no match'
- the `<(list)` operator connects the output of the sort commands to named pipes that are then used as files for the join command (called Process Substitution)

Comment: Hi! thank you. I did not know that we could use join even when the files are not of same length.